# Помогите с регулярным выражением Oniguruma

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая строка `myVariable := function() // Comment or /* Comment*/`, для нее есть регулярка:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\s*(:=)\s*(.+)(?=\/\/|\/\*)
```

Работает только если есть `//` или `/*`, но мне нужно как бы чтоб матчило первые 3 группы даже если этого комментария и не нету, а если он есть то уже пропускать комментарий.

Скрин для детальности:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Oniguruma это так называется библиотека (гугл намекает на это)? Если охото парсить код регулярками, то почему не удалить перед этим комментарии?

Comment: если комментарии в конце опциональны и уже выделены в группу в регулярке, то просто добавь `?` после этой группы и она станет необязательной

Comment: @gil9red мне не нужно удалять их так как я делаю подсветку синтакса для кода

Comment: @Lexx918 можете навести пример? Я никак сообразить не могу.

Comment: Так если вы пишете шаблон для Онигурумы, зачем тестируете в PCRE? В `fn = new func()`  нет `:`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew так я не знаю где можно тестировать Oniguruma, тестирую на regex101, а уже дорабатываю с textmate. С `:` знаю, забыл добавить, но сути дела не меняет, все равно матчить не будет.

Comment: Попробуйте `^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\s*(:=)\s*(.+?)(?:\/\/|\/\*)?$`. [Ссылка на тест-сайт для Онигурумы](https://rubular.com/r/FhdnZPzpH2Wbph)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо за сайт, жаль подсветки нету, на да ладно... Но это все равно не правильная регулярка, она матчит `3. function() // Comment or /* Comment*/` когда матчить должна только `function()`, комментарий как бы остается в стороне не тронутым, на скрине выше это показано. `sample := 1 + 2 // Matching` , то есть `// Matching` никак не трогает, он не входит не в глобальную видимость, не в группу.

Comment: Ну никак моя регулярка не может найти совпадения в `3. function() // Comment or /* Comment*/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew как не может?
`Match 1
1. myVariable
2. :=
3. function() // Comment or /* Comment*/
Match 2
1. fn
2. :=
3. new func()`

Comment: Какую строку вы тестируете?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я тестирую по вашей ссылке, ничего не меняя, перейдите на https://rubular.com/r/FhdnZPzpH2Wbph и увидите что в `Match 1` в третьей группе будет `function() // Comment or /* Comment*/`

Comment: https://rubular.com/r/gwK6HMazuvV4LR?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew о, спасибо, вот теперь то что надо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
/^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\s*(:=)\s*(.+?)(?=(?:(?:\/\/|\/\*).*)?$)/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://rubular.com/r/gwK6HMazuvV4LR).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)` - Подмаска №1: одна и более букв, цифр или знаков подчёркивания
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `(:=)` -  Подмаска №2: `:=`
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `(.+?)` -  Подмаска №3: 1 и более любых символов кроме перевода на новую строку, как можно меньше
- `(?=(?:(?:\/\/|\/\*).*)?$)` - (блок предварительного просмотра вперёд) опциональная строка: `//` или `/*` + любые 0 и более символов, отличных от символа перехода строки, а затем конец строки.